# "Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 2 on filter Parsed_amerge_2" ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio

The error I'm getting is in the title.

I want to merge the two audio streams from a video into one (yes, I've checked if there is two and there is). This is the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-2:720,format=yuv420p[v];[0:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 output.mp4
```

Any ideas why I could be getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a filtergraph, each pad is associated with a single stream. And a specifier such as `0:a` will match the first stream that qualifies. You need to specify two pads and fully specify the input streams.

```
[0:a:0][0:a:1]amerge=inputs=2[a]
```

Comment: Will this throw an error if only one input audio stream is inputted? I'm using it in a kind of automated program, and some videos may only have one audio stream, while others may have 2.

Comment: No. of inputs should be equal to the inputs value of amerge.